# Jersey client gets status 504 (UniformInterfaceException) - how to configure client timeout?

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

Our Jersey client gets the exception below from the server.

```
Got exception from API:POST http://my-host.com/api/x/y returned a response status of 504 Gateway Timeout, Stack trace: com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: POST http://my-host.com/api/x/y returned a response status of 504 Gateway Timeout
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:698)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$300(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:574)
at com.g.e.s.i.t.XYZ.callResource(ABC.java:84)
at ...
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

This is the client creation code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
JacksonJaxbJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
provider.setMapper(mapper);
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
    clientConfig.getSingletons().add(provider);
    Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
    client.setConnectTimeout(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    client.setReadTimeout(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return client.resource(url);
```

So, we're trying to setup the maximum timeout for the client but does not help.


Any one knows how to configure the client for the timeout?
May be is better to handle the Tomcat timeout? (how?) although I think it is behind some load balancer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code for setting client read time out.

```
clientConfig.getProperties().put(ClientConfig.PROPERTY_READ_TIMEOUT,30000);//30 seconds read timeout
```

Try below code for setting client connection time out.

```
clientConfig.getProperties().put(ClientConfig.PROPERTY_CONNECT_TIMEOUT,30000);//30 seconds for connection timeout
```

Comment: Works great :) thanks! Although finally the reason was to increase the timeout on the server side :)

Comment: @sreemanth pulagam can you please explain why one uses this Read and Connect timeouts? I am using the same with my Jersey client. I have set a timeout of 5 secs for both connect and read. And to test I have put a thread sleep in my service for 6 secs. I get a timeout exception but after that my service resumes and gives response as normal. My requirement is to set a timeout for the service to respond and if it is passed it should come out and try again. Also I need to set number of attempts the client should try to connect.